# Windows: redirect ReadFile to run process and pipe it's stdout

Tags: windows, driver, code-injection, readfile, minifilter

I was wondering how hard it would be to create a set-up under Windows where a regular ReadFile on certain files is being redirected by the file system to actually run (e.g. ShellExecute) those files, and then the new process' stdout is being used as the file content streamed out to the ReadFile call to the callee...

What I envision the set-up to look like, is that you can configure it to denote a certain folder as 'special', and that this extra functionality is then only available on that folder's content (so it doesn't need to be disk-wide).  It might be accessible under a new drive letter, or a path parallel to the source folder; the location it is hooked up to is irrelevant to me.

To those of you that wonder if this is a classic xy problem: it might very well be ;)  It's just that this idea has intrigued me, and I want to know what possibilities there are.  In my particular case I want to employ it to #include content in my C++ code base, where the actual content included is being made up on the spot, different on each compile round.  I could of course also create a script to create such content to include, call it as a pre-build step and leave it at that, but why choose the easy route.

Maybe there are already ready-made solutions for this?  I did an extensive Google search for it, but came out empty handed.  But then I'm not sure I already know all the keywords involved to do a good search...

When coding up something myself, I think a minifilter driver might be needed intercepting ReadFile calls, but then it must at that spot run usermode apps from kernel space - not a happy marriage I assume.  Or use an existing file system driver framework that allows for usermode parts, but I found the price of existing solutions to be too steep for my taste (several thousand dollars).
And I also assume that a standard file system (minifilter) driver might be required to return a consistent file size for such files, although the actual data size returned through ReadFile would of course differ on each call.  Not to mention negating any buffering that takes place.
All in all I think that a create-it-yourself solution will take quite some effort, especially when you have never done Windows driver development in your life :)  Although I see myself quite capable of learning up on it, the time invested will be prohibitive I think.

Another approach might be to hook ReadFile calls from the process doing the ReadFile - via IAT hooking, or via code injection.  But I want this solution to more work 'out-of-the-box', i.e. all ReadFile requests for these special files trigger the correct behavior, regardless of origin.  In my case I'd need to intercept my C++ compiler (G++) behavior, but that one is called on the fly by the IDE, so I see no easy way to detect it's startup and hook it up quickly before it does it's ReadFiles.  And besides, I only want certain files to be special in this regard; intercepting all ReadFiles for a certain process is overkill.

Comment: @downvoter: want to elaborate on the downvote?  I know that to the ones in the know this might seem a bit like an trivial, obvious, irrelevant or foolish question, but I currently lack this deeper understanding.  This post is more for me (and maybe others) to learn from this, than to lead to a real solution (if it exists of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like [FUSE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) (which I used with profit many times), but for Windows. Apparently there's [Dokan](https://dokan-dev.github.io/), I've never used it but seems to be well known enough (and, at very least, can be used as an inspiration to see "how it's done").

Comment: Thanks for that!  After diving into it a bit it seems to use MinGW (which I also use).  It also takes a lot of the hassle out of development, and allows for usermode code to run.  Now it's time to figure out if it's total overkill for my use case, but it seems like a fun project!